# localhost url for windroye android emulator

Tags: android, http

I wrote a wcf service application and want to access it from an android application.
When I used android studio emulator I replaced `localhost` in the URL by `10.0.2.2`.
Now I am using windroye emulator in my win 8.1 pc. What URL should I use?

```
public static String connect(String json) {
    String url="http://10.0.2.2:1755/service1.svc/func";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity se = null;
    try {
        se = new StringEntity(json);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    httppost.setEntity(se);
    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    String result = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        // Examine the response status
        Log.i("Praeda", response.getStatusLine().toString());

        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: i tried, get exception e=null

Comment: ... `same` address as before?

Comment: yes. String url="http://128.0.0.1:1755/service1.svc/func";

Comment: I meant this: `String url="http://10.0.2.2:1755/service1.svc/func";`

Comment: sure i tried. its not working.